# Use of 'A' vs. 'The'?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

The rule states that:

> Use (A) the first time you mention something, and (The) the second time you mention the same thing.

Kindly, consider the following example: (source: English for Starters 9)

> ((I'm going to tell you about a city called Tripoli, in the north of Lebanon. It is ***a*** city with lots of beautiful old houses.))

According to the rule, we should say:

> ((It is ***the*** city with lots of beautiful old houses))

because it is the second time we mention the word (city).
Why did we use (a) instead of (the) in this situation?

Comment: That "rule" is wrong.  *A* is used for nonspecific things (Tripoli is *a* city, because it's one of many) and *the* is used for specific ones (Tripoli is *the* city where I was born).

Comment: No, the rule is right. It's the OP's interpretation of it that is wrong. One does move from A to THE, but the THE has to go with the same object.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, it is not the number of times *something* is mentioned, rather

> **A**

is used when being *nonspecific*, whereas

> **The**

is used when being ***specific*** or pointing out ***uniqueness*** or ***utmost***

> I'm going to tell you about **a** city called Tripoli.
>   **The** city *(that I just mentioned)* has lots of beautiful houses.

"***the city***" is used since you are specifying the city you just mentioned in the previous sentence

This is a different pattern to

> I'm going to tell you about **a** city called Tripoli.
>   It is **a** city with lots of beautiful houses.
>   It is also **a** city with pre-Roman and pre-Ottoman architecture.
>   It is **the** most famous and largest city in Lebanon.

Where there are many cities with "***beautiful houses***" and "***architecture***", but only one is the "***largest**" and "***most famous***".

The ordering could be changed to

> I'm going to tell you about **a** city called Tripoli.
>   It is **the** most famous and largest city in Lebanon.
>   It is **a** city with lots of beautiful houses.
>   It is also **a** city with pre-Roman and pre-Ottoman architecture.

A native speaker would not have a problem with either ordering.

Maybe this makes it clearer the difference in using "***the***" vs "***a***", but it is not dependent on the "**ordering**".

Answer (score 0):

The rule is right, your example from the book is right.

Your interpretation is incorrect:

Your example in the book is correct. The first mention is **A city called Tripoli**. The second mention would then become **The city, that specific city**. BUT in **their example**, they continue with the idea of A city: it has not yet become The city. It is still **a city among others in Lebanon**.

Still referring to Tripoli.

If you say: *It is a city with lots of beautiful homes* that means **there might be others like it in Lebanon**.

**The movement from A to THE has to refer to the same thing**. **If you start with A and keep A**, that means the thing (city of Tripoli) is ONE of what could be others like it.