# The use of "the" or "a" in context

Tags: articles

Tell me please if have to use "a" or "the" in the following dialogue:

> Person 1: what did that tablet cost you?
>
> Person 2: It costs 200 dollars. But I must say it is **an**/**the** approximate sum. My dad bought it me.

I think "the" should be used, but not sure. And Could I say it is *an/the around sum*?

Comment: correction: bought it _for_ me.

Comment: I posted this below and it was deleted. So, instead of reposting it is as an below, here is it is, and shows that what I said is what LawrenceC says. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157664/use-of-a-vs-the/157680#157680 Yes, an approximate sum, first mention. Second mention: the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, it's not the biggest error.
I'd concentrate more on number/tense agreement.
I'd also consider "bought it me" far too colloquial to use as an ESL.
I struggle using contractions like that & I'm a Northern Brit living in the South, where it would never be used at all.

I would recast the answer as

> It **cost** *[past tense]* 200 dollars, but I must say...
>
> 1. it [*or* that] is an approximate sum.
> 2. that is the approximate cost.
> 3. it's [that's] an approximation
> 4. it's [that's] a guess
>
> ...My dad bought it **for** me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the tablet actually cost $207.

$200 is one approximate sum, and $201 is another approximate sum. (You can continue this to come up with many approximate sums, depending on what number range you want to fit into your definition or *approximate*.)

Therefore, *an* is the correct word because there is no *single* approximate sum in the sentence you used, and $200 is just one of several possibilities you could have relayed.

---

However, the definite article would be correct in this sentence:

> $200 was **the** approximate sum that I you about earlier.

Here, you only *did* relay to him a single approximate sum.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use *the X* unless you were talking about X previously, or X is something observed previously by both parties in the conversation.

A good test - if the question "X of what" or "which X" makes sense, and both parties in the conversation can answer it, then you can say *the X*.

> Person 2: It costs 200 dollars. But I must say it is an/the approximate sum.

*Sum* means "a total that is obtained when you add 2 or more things together" - and you haven't previously talked about a total of anything.

Where the confusion is: *Sum* does not mean "what X costs."

> Person 2: It costs 200 dollars. But I must say it is *the approximate cost*.

You just mentioned *cost* in the first sentence.  The question "cost of what" makes sense, and can be answered by both parties in the conversation.

So saying *the approximate cost* is fine.

Comment: It is **an approximate sum**. But it is not **the sum** I would have  paid. This happens all the time in English. You move from *a* to *the*.

Comment: I don't agree that sum is completely incorrect. Definition 3 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sum#Noun) is just "a quantity of money", which works even if it's not the best option.

Comment: 1. MONEY an amount of money:   _He owes me a large sum of money._ LDOCE5

Comment: Idk, you can't say "Give me my sum" and it mean the same as "give me my money."  *Sum* can mean *money* but won't imply cost like "How much money?" will.

Comment: This is about using "a" [some thing] the first time some thing is mentioned followed by "the" [thing], the second time it is mentioned. "He owes me **a** large sum of money". "**The** sum was agreed to by him when we discussed it." One moves in conversation from a thing to the thing. It is typical in English speech and writing. If everyone would take a breath and think about this, it will become evident.

Comment: I downvoted because sum does not always mean total. It is an error to claim that it does.